# Strict concavity of conditional mutual information

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Let $I(X;Y\vert Z)$ be the conditional mutual information between random variables $X$, $Y$, and $Z$. We know that $I(X;Y\vert Z)$ is the mutual information between $X\vert Z$ and $Y\vert Z$, and also, based on Chapter 3, Lemma 3.3 in "Physical-Layer Security: From Information Theory to Security Engineering" by Bloch et al., we know that $I(X;Y\vert Z)$ is a "concave" functional of $p_X(x)$.

My question is, provided that we have the degardedness condition, i.e., $p(x,y,z) = p(z\vert y) p(y\vert x) p_X(x)$, do we have the "strict concavity" of $I(X;Y\vert Z)$ in $p_X(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ be a length-$n$ probability vector, $H(p)$ be the entropy of $p$, and $W$ be a stochastic matrix. In general, one does not get strict concavity of the mutual information
$$ I(p,W) = H(pW) - \sum_{i=1}^n p_i H(e_i W), $$
where $e_i$ is the $i$-th standard basis vector.

Since $H(\cdot)$ is strictly convex and the second term is linear in $p$, the mutual information $I(p,W)$ will be strictly convex if $W$ has rank $n$.

On the other hand, $I(p,W)$ will not be strictly convex if the null space of $W^T$ contains a vector $q$ that sums to 0.  This is because $I(p+sq,W)$ will be independent of $s$ when $p$ is uniform and $s$ is sufficiently small.

This settles the degraded case because $I(X;Y|Z) = I(X;Y)-I(X;Z)$ for the Markov chain $X-Y-Z$ and subtracting $I(X;Z)$ cannot make it concave.  Also, choosing $Z$ to be constant settles the general case for $I(X;Y|Z)$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't quite follow why $I(X;Y\vert Z) = I(X;Y)$ when $X\to Y\to Z$. As far as I know and it also can be proved when we have the Markov chain $X\to Y\to Z$, we have $I(X;Y\vert Z) = I(X;Y) - I(X;Z)$. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, $I(X;Y|Z) = I(X;Y)-I(X;Z)$ under the assumption $X-Y-Z$. I had miswrote this (and I will correct shortly). This doesn't change the conclusion though because $I(X;Y)$ can be linear and subtracting the concave function $p_X \mapsto I(X;Z)$ cannot make it concave.